# Do player change factions in Farcry 4 after receiving

Tags: far-cry-4

Spoilers as it is a question about end game. In the end, we have two options, either to let Pagan Min survive or kill him. I killed him, so obviously I can't redo that now. Apparently, if I hadn't kill him, he would have left whole of Kyrat for the player.

Now, question is, if that happens, technically, player replace Pagan Min. So, all those soldiers we were fighting becomes our own army. So, we should actually change factions, and start fighting against the golden path.

Sadly, I have no way to find out if it happens. Or if the game just glosses over that "whole kyrat is yours, you are my rightful heir" line from Pagan Min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Golden Path is leading a revolution in Kyrat.  When dealing with the leader of the old regime, you've got two choices.  Choice one is killing him, and choice two is sending him off to exile.

In either situation, you've basically routed his army, and the Golden Path takes over the government (such as it is...).  Whoever you chose to back during the plot becomes the leader of a "free Kyrat" either way.

Basically, Min is giving up his government and agreeing to leave the country, and not really granting you control of his army.

Comment: Oh, so that line was more of a "I concede defeat" type thing. I wonder why they chose that line, given the story was revolving around pagan min being player's step father. "Rightful heir to my kingdom" line confused me. :/

Answer (score 0):

After the end game mission, you still fight for the Golden Path and still can take out armies of Pagan Min. That never changes...